# Google reCaptcha not working IE sometimes

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, contact-form-7, recaptcha

Sometimes, the google recaptcha not working ate IE. Show me this log message:

> ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: recaptchaCallback

I mean sometimes because it is not always. If I did Ctrl + F5, the recaptcha appears, but if you access the page normally, through link, for example, or recaptcha does not appear, and displays the message in the console.

The recaptcha is the recaptcha of the wordpress plugin Contact Form 7.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurred because I had this code in file `functions.php`.

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5);
```

After removing these lines, it returned to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the script that contains "recaptchaCallback" is loaded after your Google recaptcha script. It needs to be loaded before.

Answer (score 0):

reCAPTCHA cannot display correctly if the IE Compatibility View is enabled for google.com. We suggest that you remove google.com from your list of sites that have Compatibility View enabled.

**Turn off Compatibility view**

**IE 10**
In Internet Explorer, press the Alt key to display the Menu bar, or press and hold the address bar and select Menu bar.
Click Tools and select Compatibility View settings.
Select google.com under "Websites you've added to Compatibility View."
Click Remove.
**IE 9**
In Internet Explorer, press the Alt key to display the Menu bar, or press and hold the address bar and select Menu bar.
Click Tools and select Compatibility View settings.
Select google.com under "Websites you've added to Compatibility View."
Click Remove.
**IE 8**
In Internet Explorer, open the Tools menu at the top and select Compatibility View Settings.
Select google.com under "Websites you've added to Compatibility View."
Click Remove.